# Sort using Iterators c++

Tags: c++

first time I started using Iterators and I have a task to make a sort, which sorts any container of int, later any of type.  So, I get lost very fast.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
//*****************************************************
template <class Type, class Iterator>
void Sort (Type arr[], Iterator beginning, Iterator ending)
{
    int * intPointer;
    intPointer = arr;
    for(auto i=beginning; i<ending-1; i++)
    {
        for (auto j=i+1; j<ending; j++)
        {
            if (*intPointer>*intPointer++) // PROBLEM
            {
                swap(&intPointer, &intPointer); //AND HERE
            }
        }
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------
template <class Type>
void swap(Type *value1, Type *value2)
{
   int temp = *value1;
   *value1 = *value2;
   *value2 = temp;
   return;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
template <class Type, class Iterator>
void display(Type arr[], Iterator beginning, Iterator ending)
{
    int * intPointer;
    intPointer = arr;
    for(auto i=beginning; i<ending; i++)
    {
        cout << *intPointer << " ";
        intPointer++;
    }
    cout << endl;
};
//*****************************************************
int main()
{
    int test[10] = {5,6,8,9,4,11,0,45,100,14};
    Sort(test, begin(test), end(test));
    display(test, begin(test), end(test));
}
```

It displays correctly(if there is something wrong tell me), but crashes on Sort(). Would be great to get some advices, how to solve that problem of pointers and get some advices how to get not lost when I will be doing sort of any type with this code. Did not find a correct information in other topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (*i > *j) // PROBLEM FIXED
{
    swap(*i, *j); //AND HERE FIXED
}
```

When you use iterators you do not need an array in the first argument. You can remove it:

```
void Sort(Iterator beginning, Iterator ending);
void display(Iterator beginning, Iterator ending);
```